# How to get a callback when an Azure Marketplace Managed Application is installed from marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace, azure-managed-app

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/azure-app-managed#define-the-technical-configuration) states:

> **Provide a notification endpoint URL:** In the Notification Endpoint URL
> box, provide an HTTPS Webhook endpoint to receive notifications about
> all CRUD operations on managed application instances of this plan
> version.

I created a simple Logic App and copied the HTTP endpoint into my MPN App Plan under the

It looks like this and has the sig at the end:

> `https://prod-08.australiaeast.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/fe287d1b9a8c48619a1b44765dad6dc7/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=C9JYfNPjvq-efsLwW66A4K4zTgx6qxGT1oH0RZZRsI0`

To test it I hit it with PostMan and confirm that it is getting an HTTP200 as per the MS Docs.

[image]

I publish the app to the marketplace:

[image]

(you can see the app live here - https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/data-drivenai1581501556049.cloudmonitor-analytics-engine)

However - the endpoint never gets called at all. I can see in the logs that no attempt (failed or past) has been made to call it.

I raised a Microsoft Support Ticket and asked a Technical Specialist, however no one can tell me how to debug it or why it is not calling back on installs or failed installs.

Has anyone seen this working?

**Update**
I found out that each PLAN has a GUID that is automatically used for deployment. Mine is "pid-34881ea9-xxxx--xxxx-xxxx-2cf731e06ef7-partnercenter" - should I be putting this on the callback notification URL as sig=ThisGUID?

Comment: UPDATE:  It turns out that I have uncovered a bug and this does indeed, not work. Microsoft Product Team have patched the issue and we have tested it in a single region. The update will be rolled out globally in the next 2 weeks after which this will now work (October 2021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example for [Managed apps with notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/publish-notifications#azure-marketplace-application-notification-schema), it shows that managed applications will send a post to `https://{your_endpoint_URI}/resource`. Can you try adding **/resource** to your listener and see if it triggers your logic app? I believe that should fix this.

Comment: Thanks - I did not notice this in the documentation. What a difference 1 word makes! I have added it to the logic app as a virtual path and will retest.

Comment: Hi Evan:  Do you know if this webhook is called during the lifecycle of an app in PREVIEW? I did not receive a callback, but it is in preview...